# Вообще есть какой-то смысл при raid5 c 1 spare hdd, использовать внешний bitmap-file?

Tags: root, hdd, raid, linux

Всем добрый день,Имеем raid5, 3 hdd + 1 spare + bitmap во внешнем файле. А есть ли в нем смысл?Основное назначение его, это быстрая перестройка массива при поломке. Но сейчас, при выходе одного из винтов, начинается процесс синхронизации со spare hdd, что в моем случае (все hdd по 2Tb) занимает ~15 часов. Т.е. мне думается, что без spare перестойка велась бы действительно исходя из bitmap, а так как-то он не при делах остается.Или я что-то не так делаю?

---

Вопрос был про bitmap file, но никто этого не видел.) вопрос закрыт

Comment: Какой контроллер??? Да и 3 винта- это минимально для 5-ки, если один гакнется, то пиши пропало.

Answer (score 2):

Для 2 ТБ 15 часов под нагрузкой многовато. У меня в софтовом 6 райде из 6 1,5 ТБ дисков 4 часа диск добавляется. Наличие spare hdd не сокращает время синхронизации массива, а избавляет от необходимости немедленно добавлять новый диск. При выходе из массива одного винта ВСЕ содержимое массива синхронизируется.Если Вы используете md, (как я полагаю) то

```
cat /sys/block/md0/md/stripe\cache\size.
```

(md0 - предполагается, что Ваш массив /dev/md0) Если ответ - 256, сделайте

```
echo 8192 > /sys/block/md0/md/stripe\cache\size
```

либо

```
echo 16384 > /sys/block/md0/md/stripe\cache\size
```

- `cat /proc/mdstat` при восстановлении покажет мгновенную скорость восстановления массива.
- `cat /sys/block/md0/md/stripe\cache\active` покажет число используемых страйпов в процессе восстановления.

Можно также поиграть с `blockdev --setra /dev/md0, /dev/sd[a-d]`

Answer (score 0):

Краткий перевод [Write-intent bitmap на kernel.org](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Write-intent_bitmap): `bitmap` используется при

- запуске после нештатного выключения системы, т.е. если система решает, что после нештатной перезагрузки данные блока избыточности могут отличаться от непосредственно данных и решает сделать `sync` данных
- если один и тот же исправный диск был отключен, а затем добавлен в массив обратно (например, случайно питание отошло у диска или интерфейсный кабель - и чтобы не перестраивать целиком потерю диска по bitmap'у найти и восстановить только изменённые блоки)

Всё. Это единственные два случая.

При перестроении массива после умирания диска никак не помогает - вам всё равно нужно физически прочитать все данные с других выживших дисков, пересчитать по ним потерянные блоки и записать их на добавленный диск. Производительности `bitmap` так же не добавляет и даже может ухудшить производительность записи.

---

По поводу `hot spare` - лично я считаю бесполезной штукой на малом числе дисков. Вместо 3 дисков RAID5 + 1 неиспользуемый можно собрать:

- RAID6 - и вы с абсолютно той же самой полезной ёмкостью в размер двух дисков можете пережить смерть любых двух дисков из массива без риска потери всего массива во время длительного процесса перестроения и повышенной нагрузки на остальные диски
- RAID10 - аналогичная доступная ёмкость массива объёмом в два тома, лучше производительность записи, ровно те же самые гарантии что у RAID5 - переживём смерть одного любого диска (а если повезёт - то и смерть второго диска)

А где при этом преимущества RAID5 + болтающийся `hot spare` - я бы послушал рациональные доводы.